# Groovy Grails Hibernate : batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, groovy

I'm new in Hibernate and Groovy, i dont know why i got error id in this code.
My Grails version is 2.1.1

Grails-app/Domain using Hibernate

```
class Deposit implements Validateable{

BigInteger **id**
BigDecimal amount
BigDecimal currentBalance

static mapping = {
    datasource 'test'
    table 'DEPOSIT'
    id column: "ID"
    amount column: "amount"
    currentBalance column: "currentBalance"

    version false
}
```

DepositContoller

```
def depositTrx(){
    def savedata = new Deposit()    
    savedata.id=3;
    savedata.amount=122223;
    savedata.currentBalance=1511122;
    savedata.save()
    redirect(uri: "/Deposit")
}
```

if I use **id** in grails-app/Domain, i got this error:
batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

when I change grails-app/Domain: **id** become to **ide** or whatever, the code successfully save data to database, but page show me this error
null id in Deposit entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Comment: What version of grails are you using? Are you updating existing data? I think maybe assigning the ID to a new object may be the issue - could you try `def saveData = Deposit.load(3)`?

Comment: @erichelgeson i use Grails-2.1.1. i want to save(add) new transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to be able to manually assign the `id` you can set the generator to assigned:

```
static mapping = {
    id generator: 'assigned', column: "ID"
    ...
}
```

http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html